# Send Integers in Outbound Message?

Tags: webservices, wsdl, workflowoutboundmessage

Is it possible to coerce `Number` fields being sent through an `Outbound Message` to be of the `Integer` type?

Is it possible to somehow modify the `WSDL` to simply use `type="xsd:int"` instead of `type="xsd:double"`? Or do I have to define a custom `Web Service` to accomplish this end?

Comment: Since all number fields are Decimal, I'm guessing not. Not sure though.

Comment: That's my hunch as well, I just want to be sure. Seems like it would be useful to be able to customize the WSDL.

Comment: I don't think you can make the change at the Salesforce end. If you change the WSDL to indicate it is an integer it would really depend on the data you are sending and the way the receiver handles typing. I.e. If the actual data in the SOAP message could be parsed as an integer by the receiver then you should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to build your own XML tree instead of using `Outbound Messaging`. We tried to advise the client it was a bad idea, but they didn't listen.